# After pressing Left Control the D key doesn't work until I press it again

Tags: windows-8.1

This is a very odd issue, however when I press the LControl key on my keyboard the "D" button doesn't work until I hit it again.

Comment: Is it *only* `D`? If not, then it could be a bad line in the keyboard. If so, then it’s probably a software issue.

Comment: Only D. All other keys work fine